# building blender

Tags: python, compile

I'm starting to build blender. For some reason CMake isn't showing configurations for the following:

- PYTHON_LIBRARY
- PYTHON_LIBPATH
- PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
- PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR

That aside what would the PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR or PYTHON_LIBRARY be?
I just compiled Python 3.7.11 to use while building and the only directories that build are: bin, include, lib, and share.
would PYTHON_LIBRARY=**lib/libpython3.7m.a**?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to part of my question on Blender's wiki:
[Using Pyenv with Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/User:Brita/Configs/Pyenv). I'm going to copy the variables here so they aren't just Blender's wiki.

This doesn't completely answer my question cause PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR is the same as PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR.

```
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/3.67.2/include/python3.7m
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/include/python3.7m
PYTHON_LIBPATH:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib
PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/libpython3.7m.a
PYTHON_LINKFLAGS:STRING=-Xlinker -export-dynamic
PYTHON_VERSION:STRING=3.7
PYTHON_NUMPY_PATH:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/venv-blender/lib64/python3.7/site-packages
PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/venv-blender/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON_REQUESTS_PATH:PATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/venv-blender/lib64/python3.7/site-packages
PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES:FILEPATH=/home/stitch/.pyenv/versions/venv-blender/lib64/python3.7/site-packages
```